# Deleted all certificates by mistake. How to recreate?

Tags: keychain, certificate

I started seeing an issue in Chrome (38 on OSX 10.7.5) accessing GitHub. I got a Privacy error. One of the recommendations on SuperUser, and the reply I got from GitHub support, was to delete all expired certificates in Keychain Access, close the browser, and reboot the machine. I followed the advice.

Now, I cannot access many other sites: LinkedIn, StackExchange sites etc. - all with the same error. I'm forced to use another browser (which btw, shows an error next to the HTTPS lock icon). The Keychain Access certificates view does not repopulate. I might have deleted something I shouldn't, but shouldn't new certificates be downloaded as needed? What do I need to do to gain access to all the HTTPS sites again?

Comment: Do you have a backup? If so, you can restore the files. If not, you can back up, erase and reinstall the OS and then restore the backup.

Comment: Reinstall the OS? For SSL certificates???

Comment: There is a user keychain, a system keychain and frankly, the procedure to do that is well documented and it takes about 3 minutes of your time to execute things. Who says you'll not make things worse by trying to muck with ssl trust chains... The lack of detail in your post made me choose the easiest fix for you. I'll make a real answer with the locations of the files you have mistakenly removed parts of the trust chain.

Comment: The same thing happened to me I need help it said it didn't have a secure connection so I searched up advice and it said to delete all keychains that looked useless. I did that not thinking about what I was doing, and now I can't access anything on google chrome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally solved the issue by opening the web sites that misbehaved, one at a time, in Safari. From there you proceed to trust each and every certificate. They are then re-added to your keychain. More can be found [in this KB](http://support.apple.com/kb/PH10968).

I'd like to thank @bmike for doing his best to assist. Restoring from backup would probably work (if I had one - silly me).

Comment: Nice answer - be sure to tick it as the solution when the timeout expires. Glad you found the add one cert option. Also, I realized you might get everything back in order if you apply the latest combo update from apple.com/downloads...

Comment: I believe that another solution to this problem would be to "Reinstall OSX" just not fresh. When you boot to recovery and reinstall, it just puts a fresh copy on top of what you have and doesn't modify any user data, so running a reinstall would also restore the certs on the system :)

Answer (score 6):

Restore the contents of these three directories from a recent backup:

```
~/Library/Keychains
/Library/Keychains
/System/Library/Keychains
```

On my system this comprises 18 files and a subdirectory in the user folder `~/Library/Keychains`

Comment: I do not have a backup. All I want to do is force the browser to re-download the certificates. I'm not sure what's missing there.

Comment: The trust chain doesn't work that way on OSX. It would be a huge security risk to have the browser heal itself downloading new certs from the Internet, no?

Comment: So how did the certs get there in the first place?

Comment: I can't even begin to guess what cert chain you had. They can be added by MDM profile, file if the user takes action, but the vast, vast majority of people only get certificates in their keychain as part of the OS initial installation and OS updates from Apple exclusively.

Comment: I'm still trying to wrap my head around why sites SSL certificates have anything to do with my keychain, and not browser specific. If I browse to https://apple.stackexchange.com, shouldn't the browser decide whether it's a bogus cert or not? What does my keychain have to do with it?

Comment: @TravelingTechGuy Sorry for the late response. Apple stores the root certificates in the keychain so that some trust can be pre-established. I'm more familiar with Safari, but pretty sure that Chrome on OS X also relies on elements stored in the keychain to root the chain of trust. Basically everyone that gets in this door, can have their root certificate shipped with Apple updates: http://www.apple.com/certificateauthority/ca_program.html

Comment: Thank you for this answer - I was trying to fix a cert issue that Security Update 2015-004 introduced where my Verisign certs were invalid, but I accidentally deleted the System Root Verisign certs. I had a backup, and I restored my old file in `/System/Library/Keychains` and now that older copy seems to have sorted out all the issues I was having in the first place that the update introduced.